# Inserting into a HTML div tag from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched online for a solution to my problem, but I can't seem to fix it.
I've tried also using a validator, but still nothing gives. Sorry if you think that this is a repeated question. I just can't seem to find anything. Here's what I did:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <p><strong>User Information:</strong></p>

 <button onclick="getUserInfo()">Begin</button>

 <div id=”content”>Hello</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function getUserInfo(){

 var name = prompt("What is your full name?", "Name");
 var age = prompt("How old are you?", "Age");
     if (name !== null && age !== null) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
    "Hello, my name is " + name + " and I'm " + age + " years old.";

}           
 }
 </script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: who is person?  in this condition `if (person !== null && age !== null)`

Comment: sorry, name. I just changed it, but still nothing appears to the screen after the prompts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<div id=”content”>Hello</div>
```

to

```
<div id="content">Hello</div>
```

It might be the issue here.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot. I actually spotted a difference but thought they were the same.